# numerical integration over a vector of observations in R using `integrate`

Tags: r

I need to evaluate the following integration for a vector of observations but each time I get this error message:

> "Error in (((r * uu) - mu)) %*% (solve(var.cov)) :    non-conformable
>   arguments In addition: Warning messages: 1: In r * uu :   longer
>   object length is not a multiple of shorter object length 2: In (r *
>   uu) - mu :" here is my code:

```
mu=c(0,1)
var.cov=matrix(c(1,0,0,1),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=T)
f=function(r,theta){
  uu=c(cos(theta),sin(theta))
  a=drop(t(uu)%*%solve(var.cov)%*%(uu))
  b=drop(t(uu)%*%solve(var.cov)%*%(mu))
  c=drop(-0.5*t(mu)%*%solve(var.cov)%*%mu)
  d=drop(b/sqrt(a))
  aa=(1/(2*pi*a*sqrt(det(var.cov))))*exp(c)*(1+((d*pnorm(d))/dnorm(d)))
  p=(((r*uu)-mu))%*%(solve(var.cov))%*%t((r*uu)-mu)
  pp=exp((-0.5)*p)
  ppp=(r/(2*pi*(sqrt(det(var.cov)))))*pp
  final=ppp/aa
  formula=r*final
  return(formula)
} 

expec=function(theta){
  integrate(f, lower=0, upper=Inf, theta=theta)$value
}
v.expec=Vectorize(expec)
theta=c(1.18,2.62,1.63,1.74,1.71,1.34,1.58)
v.expec(theta)
```

Comment: try removing the transposition in `p` (thats what yields the error) such as `... %*%((r*uu)-mu)`. There's also an error when calling `f` through `integrate()` but I don't really know how that function works..

Comment: thanks alot but even when I removed (t), I still get the same error message

Comment: There are multiple problems in your code. Your current error message has nothing to do with integration. Your function f simply does not work. Try `f(10, 1.18)` and you will get the same error message. You can get by that problem by changing your code for computing p to     `p=(((r*uu)-mu))%*%(solve(var.cov))%*% matrix((r*uu)-mu)`  That will make your function work, but the rest has other problems.

Comment: thanks alot, but even when I used matrix,I still get the same error